# Is the Lawrence–Krammer representation faithful, reduced modulo p?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, knot-theory, braid-groups

It is well-known that the braid group $B_n$ is linear for every $n$ by the Lawrence–Krammer (or LKB) representation. It embeds $B_n$ faithfully into $\mathrm{GL}\left(\frac{n(n-1)}{2},\mathbb{Z}[q^{\pm 1},t^{\pm 1}]\right)$. My question is: is the representation still faithful modulo $p$, where $p$ prime?

The motivation of this question is a similar question about the Burau representation. Cooper and Long proved in the 1990s that the Burau representation is not faithful on $B_4$ modulo 2 and 3. On the other hand, we may prove the contrary on $B_3$.

I briefly read the papers of Krammer and Bigelow, but their faithfulness proofs used the order on $\mathbb{Z}$ in some sense, and don't seem easily applicable to the mod $p$ cases. Is it correct?

I guess the $B_3$ case is relatively simple by using some proper specialization, but $B_n$ for $n\ge 4$ seems hard to me. I'm no expert on the representation, and if the question is not trivial, is there any available reference on it?

Comment: I thought there was some work on this.  Perhaps try contacting Long or Bigelow directly?

Comment: I doubt it is faithful mod p, but it's just a guess

Comment: @RyanBudney Thank you. In fact, I didn't know if this would seem like a basic question when asked. I'll ask someone directly if there is no answer for a while.